# Recurrence relation complexity

Tags: recurrence-relations

I just learned about recurrences and I just can't solve this problem. I have this recurrence relation:

$T(n)=k * T(n / k)$
$T(0)=1$,

where k is a constant number.

I tried drawing a recurrence tree or replacing for lower n-s but no success. I hope you can help me with an idea!

Comment: Is the formula for the recursion correct?  $T(n)=kT(nk)$ doesn't look like a recursive expression. How does step $n$ recurse to step $n-1$?

Comment: Sorry, i edited it wrong. Now is correct

Comment: Still wrong. $n/k$ may not be an integer, and it's only $0$ if $n$ is $0$.

Comment: You have to use $T(n) = kT(\lfloor n/k \rfloor)$ for this to make sense. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
T(n) &= k~T(k~n) \\
     &= k^2~T(k^2~n) \\
     &= k^3~T(k^3~n) \\
     & \vdots \\
     &= k^z~T(k^z~n) \\
\end{align}$$

So which $z$ to choose?  Let's make the base case be $T(1) = c$, so

$$k^z~n = 1$$
$$\log(k^z~n) = \log(1)$$
$$z~\log(k) + \log(n) = 0$$
$$z = -\frac{\log(n)}{\log(k)}$$
$$z = \log_k(n^{-1})$$

So we have

$$\begin{align}
T(n) &= k^{\log_k(n^{-1})} T(k^{\log_k(n^{-1})} ~ n) \\
     &= n^{-1} T(1) \\
     &= \frac{c}{n}
\end{align}$$

So as you can see, $T(n) = k~T(k~n)$ doesn't actually depend on $k$ at all.  Any $T$ that has this property for one $k$ will have it for any other $k$ (for $0 < k < 1$ anyway).

Unfortunately, since $T(n)$ is monotonically decreasing (as opposed to asymptotically increasing), this isn't a good problem to learn complexity with.

Comment: I think you solved it for a wrong version of the recurrence, i edited it because i wrote it wrong. Sorry!

Comment: @RubenP Can you adopt this answer to your edited case?  It should be straightforward if you understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that
only integer parameters are used,
so the correct recurrence is
$T(n)=k * T(\lfloor n / k \rfloor)
$.

Correcting DanielV's answer,
since
$\lfloor \lfloor n/k \rfloor /k \rfloor
=\lfloor n/k^2 \rfloor
$,
by induction
$T(n)=k^m * T(\lfloor n / k^m \rfloor)
$
for
$k^m \le n
$.
If $m$ is the smallest value
such that
$k^m > n$
(this is
$m > \log(n)/\log(k)$
or
$m = \lceil \log(n+1)/\log(k) \rceil$
),
then,
since
$T(0) = 1$,
$T(n)
=k^m
$.

Since
$\log(n+1)/\log(k)
\le m
<1+\log(n+1)/\log(k)
$,
$n+1
\le k^m
< k(n+1)
$.

Therefore
$n+1
\le T(n)
< k(n+1)
$,
so
$T(n)
=\Theta(n)
$.

Notice that,
for the upper bound of
$T(n)
= O(n)
$,
the constant hidden by the
$O(n)$
depends on $k$.
Since this does not depend on $n$,
this is OK.

Comment: Indeed, in general $$\lfloor \lfloor a / b \rfloor / c \rfloor = \lfloor a / (b~c)  \rfloor = \lfloor \lfloor a / c \rfloor / b \rfloor $$ .  Also since he is asking for asymptotic behavior, I think that it is fair to assume that he is working with $\mathbb R$ instead of just $\mathbb N$.  Same answer either way though (except that the initial case shouldn't be $T(0)$).

Comment: Bot if you work with R, you never get to 0, so the recursion never terminates.